# Empty taxonomy items for CPT in admin grid

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

In admin grid for post taxonomy, if I'll click on "Items" link, I'll get all post, associated with this taxonomy `/wp-admin/edit.php?category_name=test`. But this won't work for taxonomy for Custom Post Type. For example, `/wp-admin/edit.php?cpt=test&post_type=cpt` displaying 0 items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct link should look like this:

```
/wp-admin/edit.php?{taxonomy_slug}={term_slug}&post_type={cpt_slug}
```

**For example**.
If you have taxonomy `brand` and it has term (category) `test`, your link will be:

```
/wp-admin/edit.php?brand=test&post_type=CPT
```

Comment: In my case, taxonomy name and CPT slug is equal, so links is the same with your. But result is empty.

Comment: Slugs should be unique. I bet you see an empty list because you are using the same slug for custom post type and taxonomy. This will also cause address collisions, e.g. `/cpt/some-name/`, may be a single CPT page or list of posts from the `some-name` term.

Comment: You're right. Now it's okay. Thanks!